# What were the filler episodes of Maison Ikkoku?

Tags: maison-ikkoku

While watching *Maison Ikkoku*, I noted the episodes in which the main story does not progressing. I found 23 episodes at total. I need someone who has read the manga to confirm them, or add/remove episodes from my list.

```
10 - Trip to sea
11 - Kentarou's first love
15 - Theatre club
16 - Kyoko injures her leg
20 - Shiner eye
21 - Kitten Kyoko
27 - The dog Soichiro is lost
28 - 3-legged race
29 - Festival ends in well
32 - Stupid egg
36 - Akemi's story
37 - Dress up
41 - Onsen
44 - Youtsuya's secret
46 - Ice skating
47 - Work at tavern
49 - Mitaka's dog fear
50 - Elder man moves in
51 - Ikkoku-han torn down?
67 - Grandma comes
68 - Baseball
69 - Kiss mark
70 - Grandma leaves
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to know what episodes didn't follow the manga?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Isn't that the definition of "filler"?

Comment: Well, you talk in your question about episodes where the plot isn't progressing, which isn't necessarily mutually exclusive from not following the manga. Hence my clarification.

Comment: Lists of fillers can work in this format (e.g. [Which episodes of Bleach are filler?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3018/24)) but IMO it will work better if you phrase it as a self-answered question rather than a request for us to check your own list. The current post (including the request for someone to check) should be an answer to the question "Which episodes of Maison Ikkoku are filler?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a similar list back in 2003 when I was watching the series for the second time through. I had read the manga before that, though I don't remember whether I took it into consideration when making the list. In general the anime follows the manga very accurately - if we ignore some blatant filler such as episode 32 (Yotsuya's egg; IIRC even its drawing style differs, so maybe the animators were using it for practice).

Your list corresponds to the B and C ratings in my list; B doesn't advance the main story but still e.g. develops the characters, whereas C is a pure filler episode. Except for a couple of episodes, our lists are similar.

It's interesting to notice that after episode 70 there are no filler episodes, and also on average the ratio of content to filler episodes is much better than in many other anime series. :)

```
A: Important part of the story
B: Could be skipped but is still worth watching
C: Totally irrevelant

01 A    + + +
02 A    + + +
03 A    + + +
04 A    + + +
05 A    + + +
06 A    + + +
07 A    + + +
08 A    + + +
09 A    + + +
10 A    + + +
11 B    + +
12 A    + + +
13 A    + + +
14 A    + + +
15 A    + + +
16 A    + + +
17 A    + + +
18 A    + + +
19 A    + + +
20 B    + +
21 B    + +
22 A    + + +
23 A    + + +
24 A    + + +
25 A    + + +
26 A    + + +
27 A    + + +
28 B    + +
29 C    +
30 A    + + +
31 A    + + +
32 C    +        not in manga
33 B    + +
34 A    + + +
35 A    + + +
36 C    +
37 C    +
38 A    + + +
39 A    + + +
40 A    + + +
41 B    + +
42 A    + + +
43 A    + + +
44 C    +
45 A    + + +
46 C    +        not in manga
47 B    + +
48 A    + + +
49 A    + + +
50 C    +
51 C    +
52 A    + + +
53 A    + + +
54 A    + + +
55 A    + + +
56 A    + + +
57 A    + + +
58 A    + + +
59 A    + + +
60 A    + + +
61 A    + + +
62 A    + + +
63 A    + + +
64 A    + + +
65 A    + + +
66 A    + + +
67 A    + + +
68 C    +
69 B    + +
70 A    + + +
71 A    + + +
72 A    + + +
73 A    + + +
74 A    + + +
75 A    + + +
76 A    + + +
77 A    + + +
78 A    + + +
79 A    + + +
80 A    + + +
81 A    + + +
82 A    + + +
83 A    + + +
84 A    + + +
85 A    + + +
86 A    + + +
87 A    + + +
88 A    + + +
89 A    + + +
90 A    + + +
91 A    + + +
92 A    + + +
93 A    + + +
94 A    + + +
95 A    + + +
96 A    + + +
```

Comment: I'll check at least the C episodes, that whether they are in the manga or not, and add comments to them.