# Which episodes of Fairy Tail are anime-exclusive?

Tags: fairy-tail

Up to episode 175, I know Fairy Tail has some episodes which are not in the manga.

If I want to watch the series again but not the episodes that are anime-exclusive, which ones should I skip?

*This question is inspired by [Which episodes of Bleach are fillers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3018/2413), I just decided to do the same for Fairy Tail*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These following episodes list the content which are only present in the anime of Fairy Tail, not in the manga. 
This is a list of episodes defined as **anime exclusive** in the [Fairy Tail Wikia](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Episodes)

Compactly, it gives episodes: **19, 69-72, 74-75, 125-150, 204-218, 221, 223-225**

### Galuna Island Arc

- **Episode 19** - Challenging!

### Daphne Arc

- **Episode 69** - Call of the Dragon
- **Episode 70** - Natsu Vs. Gray!!
- **Episode 71** - Friendship Will Overcome the Dead
- **Episode 72** - Fairy Tail Wizards
- **Episode 74** - Wendy's First Big Mission?!
- **Episode 75** - The 24-Hours Endurance Road Race

### Key of the Starry Sky Arc

- **Episodes 125-150** - This whole arc is anime exclusive

### Eclipse Celestial Spirits Arc

- **Episodes 204-218** - Stake My Life on Hospitality - Believe
- **Episode 221** - The White Silver Labyrinth
- **Episode 223** - Kemokemo Arrived!
- **Episode 224** - The Place You Came Before
- **Episode 225** - The Thunder Man

---

The series *currently* ends with Episode 235

Comment: The galuna arc is in the manga, is not a filler

Comment: According to that wiki page episode 19 is a filler episode within a canon arc.

Comment: Call of Dragon is not entirely a filler episode.
The first, say 10 minutes is canon. So it shouldn't be tagged as an entirely filler episode.

Comment: The answer is correct, however it's prudent to note that the Eclipse Celestial Spirit Arc is anime exclusive but is still canon as it was written by Mashima and reportedly has (or will have) references to it in the manga.