# Which episodes of One Piece are filler?

Tags: one-piece

I want to watch One Piece, but the anime has a lot of filler content not in the manga. I'd rather not watch the filler content and only watch the episodes which are directly related to the plot. To be clear, I'm defining a filler episode as one which is not based on any story in the manga or based on extra manga chapters which have nothing to do with the overarching story.

Which episodes are filler?

---

This question is taken from [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3018/6166). I was curious about this myself after completing the One Piece manga, but to keep uniformity between similar questions, I took the same wording as [Logan-M](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/24/logan-m) had used in his question about Bleach filler.

Comment: I wonder how many episodes will be in this list...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be alot less filler in One Piece than in Naruto or Bleach.  That being said, there have been 12 filler arcs:

- Warship Island Arc (episodes 54-61)
- Post Alabasta Arc (131-135)
- Goat Island (136-138)
- Ruluka Island (139-143)
- G-8 (196-206)
- Ocean's Dream (220-224)
- Foxy Returns (225-226)
- Lovely Land (326-335)
- Spa Island (382-384)
- Little East Blue (426-429)
- Z's Ambition (575-578)
- Ceasar Retrieval (626-628)

Episodes 50, 99, 102, 213, 280-283, 291, 292, 303, 317, 318, 336, 406, 407, 492, 499, 506, 542, 590 are also listed as filler on the [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Filler_Episodes).

There are additional episodes that are part of main arc that spend time on (sometimes non-canon) details that aren't significant in the manga.  As this is subject to opinion and doesn't take an entire episode, I don't have a simple list for this.

Comment: Just a note:  There are a few cases (such as Usopp vs. Daddy) which are less clearly just filler despite being only in the anime.  Oda intended this to be included in the manga but cut it in order to have them get to the grand line by the 100th chapter.  The key glasses Usopp aquires here are retained in canon and it clearly shows his remarkable sniper skills more than anywhere else prior to that point in the series. Most filler is comparitely poor though.

Answer (score 8):

[One piece fillers](http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/one-piece)

^ pretty much tells what what to skip and what to watch:

```
canon - Watch
filler - don't
```

and if you're wondering, there are about 96 filler episodes.. (14% of the series)

```
screenshot ->
```

[image: screenshot of website]