# One Piece - How much manga is Animated?

Tags: one-piece

With respect to episode 1009 can anyone tell how much manga is Animated?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related/opposite duplicate: [Which episodes of One Piece are filler?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20088/2516) (animated from manga = non-filler = manga canon. The existing answers might have been outdated, but the mentioned sites are possibly updated).

Comment: No the mentioned websites were not updated after 700-800 episodes.

Comment: This is a good resource of keeping track of manga/anime https://onepace.net/watch. However, It is not up to date.