# Is Nel realy an Arrancar?

Tags: bleach

So when the *Ichigo* team went to the Hueco Mondo to save *Orihime*, they befriended *Nel* and her so called brothers and their pet. *Nel* introduces her self as an Arrancar and *Ichigo* says that she has the Arrancar reiatsu, but we don't see her carrying a Zanpakoto, aren't Arrancars hollows that broke their masks and **GAINED SHINIGAMI POWERS**? so is Nel realy an Arrancar?

Comment: yes she is. be aware that if you haven't seen past the rematch with Grimmjow then the explanation of why you haven't seen her Zanpakuto and the dinfinitive evidence that she is an Arrancar would be a major spoiler

Comment: I saw until they rescued Orihime and came back @Memor-X

Comment: if your talking about the season with Rurichiyo then just to point out they haven't returned. that season is non-canon and the next season after that takes off right after Grimmjow's defeat where they are still in Hueco Mondo. (i actually forgot that other people whats the filler seasons). it's this season i was referring to that has the spoiler evidence about Nel

Comment: Quoting Aizen, "since when are you under the impression that she is not ?" -smirk-

Comment: oh, OK @Memor-X, so basically they ruined the story for me with this stupid filler >:( I hate fillers. can I ask how many EPs do I have to skip for this filler?

Comment: @Henjin [this answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3019/1587) is your guide to fillers. the Captain Shuusuke Amagai Arc starts after Ichigo beats Grimmjow so if you skip that arc (which is an entire season) then you'll be back to Hueco Mondo