# Any important information I need to know if I'm skipping the filler episodes of Bleach?

Tags: bleach

I'm watching only the cannon episodes and am on ep. 111. However it seems that I missed a lot during the filler (i.e. the people with Kon.). Is this relevant information or something I should just look past?

Comment: [related](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3019/1587), especially the part that says *"Some of the other episodes include original elements or reference events from filler episodes, but these do not impact the story in the long run so you can safely ignore them."*

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to look past the information given in the filler episodes. In Bleach, some of the filler episodes are original to the anime and some are adapted from the manga. Regardless of the source, crucial information isn't given in these episodes, I promise. If any information is referenced it's unimportant to the main plot and can usually be understood through context. If not, the confusion will be brief and fleeting. (Understanding these few moments is not worth the wasted time on the filler episodes.)

To be more specific to your situation, there aren't that many filler episodes before episode 111 anyway except the Bount Arc. It's mentioned a few times afterwards, but not in a way that will confuse you. (You'll understand through context that they were a group of people that attacked the Soul Society.) Some characters are introduced, like "the people with Kon" but as I'm sure you've noticed, they don't do much. You'll get the gist just by watching the non-filler episodes. Watch out though, as you get further into Bleach, you'll be skipping more and more episodes.